# Always get JS error from default+en.I.js

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I want to know what is default+en.I.js . I always get error from it. (default+en.I.js (line 214) but i really don't know where I use this javascript.

Is it from google analytics or facebook or linkedin?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its from Google Custom Search API (in my case at least).